# How to get most recent logs using Get-WinEvent cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, shell-script

The Get-EventLog cmdlet has **-newest** parameter but how to find 100 most recent logs via Get-WinEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does using maxevents give you what you are after.  For example:

```
get-winevent -LogName System -maxevents 100 | Out-GridView
```